# log embedded server port number while starting spring boot project

Tags: spring-boot

I want to log the port of embedded server while starting up spring boot project. I am using log4j as the provider. Is there any category which will do this ?
Ex : `Tomcat started on port 8080`

Comment: it's already done by default : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http)

Comment: @stacker its not there in my case

Comment: That is happening by default. We won't be able to help you if you not describe your app and its logging configuration in particular. You can generate an app on start.spring.io and run it and you'll see that the port is logged on startup.

Comment: @stacker I am using Jetty server, its not logging, spring logs only embedded tomcat server port?